# posix setgid() not working to de-escalate priviliges

Tags: dart, posix

I'm trying to create a function to de-escalate sudo privileges.

I'm the maintainer of a the package dcli which is a dart package intended to replace bash.

https://pub.dev/packages/dcli

One of my objectives is to allow a user to de-escalate sudo privileges back to the original user's privileges for some parts of the code:

If we have a script called touch_me.dart

The user would run:
`sudo touch_me`

The touch_me.dart script would be:

```dart
void main() {
  test('isPriviliged', () {
    try {
      print('isPriviliged: ${Shell.current.isPrivilegedUser}');

      print('uid: ${getuid()}');
      print('gid: ${getgid()}');
      print('euid: ${geteuid()}');
      print('euid: ${geteuid()}');
      print('user: ${getlogin()}');
      print('SUDO_UID: ${env['SUDO_UID']}');
      print('SUDO_USER: ${env['SUDO_USER']}');
      print('SUDO_GUID: ${env['SUDO_GID']}');

  
      print('de-escalating to: uid: $originalUID, gid: $originalGID');

      print('pre-descalation euid: ${geteuid()}');
      print('pre-descalation user egid: ${getegid()}');

      releasePrivileges();

      print('post-descalation euid: ${geteuid()}');
      print('post-descalation user egid: ${getegid()}');

      touch('test.txt', create: true);

      'ls -la test.txt'.run;

      withPrivileges(() {
        print('with privileges euid: ${geteuid()}');
        print('with privileges egid: ${getegid()}');

        touch('test2.txt', create: true);

        'ls -la test2.txt'.run;
      });
    } on PosixException catch (e, st) {
      print(e);
      print(st);
    }
  });
}
 bool get isPrivilegedUser {
    return _whoami() == 'root';
  }


/// revert uid and gid to original user's id's
void releasePrivileges() {
  if (Shell.current.isPrivilegedUser) {
    var sUID = env['SUDO_UID'];
    var gUID = env['SUDO_GID'];

    // convert id's to integers.
    var originalUID = sUID != null ? int.tryParse(sUID) ?? 0 : 0;
    var originalGID = gUID != null ? int.tryParse(gUID) ?? 0 : 0;

    setegid(originalGID);
    seteuid(originalUID);
  }
}

/// Run [privilegedCallback] with root UID and gid
void withPrivileges(RunPrivileged privilegedCallback) {
  var privileged = Shell.current.isPrivilegedUser;

  if (!privileged) {
    setegid(0);
    seteuid(0);
  }

  /// run the callback method with escalated privileges.
  privilegedCallback();

  /// If the code was originally running privileged then
  /// we leave it as it was.
  if (!privileged) {
    releasePrivileges();
  }
}



typedef RunPrivileged = void Function();
```

Everything works as expected except for the change to the gid. Even though releasePrivileges calls setegid(SUDO_GID)  and SUDO_GID is 1000 the created file gets a gid of 0.

```
isPriviliged: true

uid: 0

gid: 0

euid: 0

euid: 0

user: bsutton

SUDO_UID: 1000

SUDO_USER: bsutton

SUDO_GUID: 1000

de-escalating to: uid: 1000, gid: 1000

pre-descalation euid: 0

pre-descalation user egid: 0

post-descalation euid: 1000

post-descalation user egid: 1000

-rw-r--r-- 1 bsutton root 0 Jan 18 10:23 test.txt
with privileges euid: 0

with privileges egid: 0

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 18 10:23 test2.txt
```

Edit:

Here is the simplest example that demonstrates the problem:

```dart
void main() {
  var sUID = env['SUDO_UID'];
  var gUID = env['SUDO_GID'];

  // convert id's to integers.
  var originalUID = sUID != null ? int.tryParse(sUID) ?? 0 : 0;
  var originalGID = gUID != null ? int.tryParse(gUID) ?? 0 : 0;

  setegid(originalGID);
  seteuid(originalUID);

  touch('test.txt', create: true);

  'ls -la test.txt'.run;
}
```

Comment: Without the variables i.e. `setegid(1000);
  seteuid(1000);` I'm guessing it will still work the same way?

Comment: @jad see my answer. The code works perfectly, it was just my test environment.

Answer (score 0):

And the problem was my testing environment :<

In early tests I had accidently created test.txt with gid = 0.

If I re-run the test, deleting test.txt before I start, the code works as expected :<